# How to create a custom Siri command

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit

I'm new to SiriKit and now I'm trying to add a new Siri command with dynamic parameters. In iPhone if we said "Get walking directions to (location)" this command to Siri, it will open the maps and create route to that particular location. I want to do the same things with my application, If I said "Order a coffee from Cafe Coffee day" here Cafe Coffee Day can be changed. How to do it ?

I try to create an intent definition file, using that I'm able to donate it to shortcut, and I open my application using the same, but I failed to add a dynamic parameter with my Siri command. I don't want any response from Siri all I need is while hearing my command it need to open the application and do a particular task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, dynamic parameter in Siri is not an option.

But you can do one thing in this scenario:

Step 1:

- In your intent definition file add one intent with parameter named "cafeName"

[image: like this]

Step 2:

- Add intent in your shortcut named "Order a Coffee"

```
  let intent = OrderCoffeeIntent()
  intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Order a Coffee"
  return intent
```

Step 3:

- Add Specific prompt for parameter, add a prompt "From where you want to order a coffee?"

[image: like this]

Step 4:

- Now In your intent handler file you will find `func handle(intent: OrderCoffeeIntent, completion: @escaping (OrderCoffeeIntentResponse) -> Void)` method. In this method you can handle your response and pass in completion. Whether you want to continue in app or failure (in case if no value found)

```
  if let cafeName = intent.cafeName {
       if cafeName != nil {
           response = OrderCoffeeIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: nil)
       } else {
           response = OrderCoffeeIntentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil) //failure
       }
  }
```

Now You can also check for the valid cafeName and check whether its available in your list or not with the use of `func resolveCafeName(for intent: OrderCoffeeIntent, with completion: @escaping (INStringResolutionResult) -> Void)`

```
 guard let title = intent.cafeName, let _ = self.getValidCafeName(day: title) else {
       completion(INStringResolutionResult.needsValue())
       return
 }
 completion(INStringResolutionResult.success(with: title))
```

Step 5:

- Now handle your intent from `handleUserActivity` method in app delegate for UIKit or with `.onContinueUserActivity` in SwiftUI. You will get your intent data (cafeName) here and you can do your task from here.

For UIKit:

```
func application(_: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler _: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.interaction?.intent is OrderCoffeeIntent {
        // Do your task...
    }
}
```

For SwiftUI:

```
 WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
           .onContinueUserActivity("OrderCoffeeIntent") { userActivity in
                // Do your task...
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about step 5

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of parameter in the 5th step ?

Comment: @SudeepPH Yes you can take parameter from the intent (which will be in userActivity) like `userActivity.interaction?.intent.cafeName`

Answer (score -1):

> First Step - In xCode click on file -> New -> Target
>
> step 1[![For add SIRI target][1]][1] step 2, [![add SIRI
> intent][2]][2] step 3, [![select the new intent from here][3]][3] step
> 4, [![Add intent like this][4]][4] step 5, [![please added one intent
> in summary][5]][5] step 6, [![add new file and select sub class i.e.
> INExtension][6]][6] step 7, [![handle like this][7]][7] step 8,
> [![which is added at the time of target file][8]][8] step 9,
> [![response intent][9]][9]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtyyC.png   [2]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nc8I.png   [3]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrcjU.png   [4]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/osqig.png   [5]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P5Fb.png   [6]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX1t3.png   [7]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv5IH.png   [8]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuBTL.png   [9]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tevqo.png
>
> How its called please follow this instructions,
>
> 1. Open the Siri Shortcuts app on your iOS device.
> 2. Tap the "+" icon in the top right corner to create a new shortcut.
> 3. Tap "Add Action" to choose an action for your shortcut.
> 4. Select the app or service you want to use for your action and choose the specific action you want to perform.
> 5. Customize the parameters of your action as needed.
> 6. Tap "Add Action" again to add another action, if needed.
> 7. Tap the settings icon in the top right corner to set a name and icon for your shortcut.
> 8. Tap "Add to Siri" to record a custom phrase that will trigger your shortcut when spoken to Siri.
> 9. Record your custom phrase and tap "Done" to save it. Your custom Siri command is now ready to use. You can trigger it by saying your
>    custom phrase to Siri on your iOS device, or by tapping the shortcut
>    in the Siri Shortcuts app.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you tried to do it https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX1t3.png ?